# How to make the time format from h:m tt to hh:mm tt in c#

Tags: c#, time, format

I am trying to show time(s) in a dropdown. I managed to do so using this code:-

```
        DateTime dtTime = new DateTime(2015,01,01,00,00,00);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("time");

        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            string tm = dtTime.ToShortTimeString();
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["time"] = tm;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dtTime = dtTime.AddMinutes(30);
        }

        ddlTime.DataSource = dt;
        ddlTime.DataTextField = "time";
        ddlTime.DataValueField = "time";
        ddlTime.DataBind();
```

The output is :-

[image]

Now, I want to make the format hh:mm tt. for example, 1:00 AM should be 01:00 AM. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Replace ToShortTimeString(); with ToString("hh:mm tt");

Comment: Thanks to all for answers. All are correct and all answers came in within minutes. Although my question presentation was very clear, I think should have tried a bit more before asking this question. Will take care next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
dtTime.ToShortTimeString();
```

with

```
dtTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dtTime = dtTime.AddMinutes(30).ToString("HH:mm tt");
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works, but I will  have to add another string and do this. So, I am taking @fube's answer. But, this is also correct. Thank You. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
string tm = dtTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```